# How to remove icon sphere from toolbar

Tags: interface

I added by accident the sphere icon to my toolbar. How can I remove it from the toolbar? Thank you,
Have a great day,
Sandra
[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you keep pressing on the button you'll have access to a dropdown menu that will let you choose the primitive you want. You can't remove the button from the tool bar though:

[image]